# single line comment to be excluded

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing Perl script to execute on C code I want to exclude my code from running inside comments(/* and */)

```
$flag = 0;
while(<>){

if($_ =~ /\/\*/ ){
    $flag = 1; 
    }

if($_ =~ /\*\//){
   $flag = 0;
    }

if($flag == 0) {
    execute other code
    }
}
```

This works fine for multiline comments like

```
/*
  ...
  ...
*/
```

but doesn't work for single line comment like

```
/* this is an example 123 */
```

need help on regex command to exclude everything(characters, integers, special characters) between " /* " and " */ "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine what happens when your program encounters a single-line-comment (`/* comment */`):

1. It sees: `/*` so it sets `flag = 1`
2. It sees: `*/` so it sets `flag = 0` immediately afterwards
3. Flag is 0, so it executes your "other code"

Try altering the order of your if-statements:

```
$flag = 0;
while(<>){

if($_ =~ /\/\*/ ){
    $flag = 1; 
    }

if($flag == 0) {
    execute other code
    }

if($_ =~ /\*\//){
   $flag = 0;
    }    
}
```

This way you first check if your line contains `/*` and in dependence to this you "execute other code" (better to say: in this case you don't execute it). Afterwards you reset your flag if there is a `*/` on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add one more statement inisde while loop as the first statement inside it like

```
$_=~s/\/\*.*?\*\///g;
```